# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for HttpWebRequest - even after use SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Tags: vb.net, ssl, tls1.2

We are consuming one Rest API where host server configures on TLS 1.2, so for connect this api using below code but still receive "Exception - Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". This will work properly in postman and Firefox RestClient.

```
    **ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1000
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12**

    Dim POSTRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    POSTRequest.Method = "POST"
    POSTRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    POSTRequest.ContentLength = postdata.Length
    Dim tmpSource As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata)
    Dim POSTstream As Stream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream()
    POSTstream.Write(tmpSource, 0, postdata.Length)
    Dim POSTResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(POSTRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

It will be very helpful if someone point me out on right direction.

Comment: Nothing in your error description provides enough detail about the error (basically you only say that it does not work w/o further details). Setting the protocol to TLS 1.2 would help only if there would actually be protocol problems - but nothing suggests this kind of problems.

Comment: Actually this is a json api it was working one day prior with same code now its given an exception error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" at "Dim POSTstream As Stream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream()" line of code. When we google found that implement "tls12" in code which already there in existing code. The network team of API confirm they have "tls12" , however this will not work from above code. It is working from Postman.

Comment: We have test this on windows 10 and surprisingly its working absolutely fine. When call HttpWebRequest is the application using any local system resource.

Comment: *"We have test this on windows 10  and surprisingly its working absolutely fine."* - which says at least that you did not run it before on Windows 10, although you still do not say on which system it failed. HttpWebRequest is using the TLS stack of the system it is running on so the behavior might depend on the system.